# What is simplest way to sort array alternately (eg:T,T,F,F,F,T,F,T,F,F,F to T,F,T,F,T,F,T,F,T,T,T)?

Tags: c++, algorithm, for-loop

For example, I have a vector

```
vector<pair<bool,int> > v={{true,1},{true,2},{false,3},{false,4},{false,5},{true,6},{false,7},{true,8},{false,9},{false,10},{false,11}};
```

which I want to sort it so that the value of bool of adjacent element is different if possible (value of int doesn't require sorting), output should be something like:

```
0,...
1,...
0,...
1,...
.
.
.
0,...
0,...
0,...
```

I tried something like this:

```
sort(v.begin(),v.end());
for(int i=1;i<v.size()/2;i+=2){
    iter_swap(v.begin()+i,v.end()-i);
}
```

but it is not my desired output:

```
0,3
1,8
0,5
1,2
0,9
0,10
0,11
1,1
0,7
1,6
0,4
```

is there any algorithm to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partition the array, like this:

```
std::vector<std::pair<bool,int> > v={{true,1},{true,2},{false,3},{false,4},{false,5},{true,6},{false,7},{true,8},{false,9},{false,10},{false,11}};

auto p = std::partition(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const auto& p) { return !p.first; });
auto it1 = v.begin();
auto it2 = p;

while(it1 != p || it2 != v.end()) {
    if(it1 != p) {
        std::cout << it1->first << ',' << it1->second << std::endl;
        ++it1;
    }
    if(it2 != v.end()) {
        std::cout << it2->first << ',' << it2->second << std::endl;
        ++it2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create a frequency array and alternatively take one element from each part.

Comment: I wouldn't call that a frequency array, which would consist of just two counters.

Answer (score 0):

Move all items to an auxiliary array, T on the left, F on the right (you don't even need to copy the boolean). Then copy back in an alternating way.

With a little care, you can perform the two reorganizations in-place.

Answer (score 0):

You could have two iterators marching over your sequence, one iterator visits all true pairs with the first element being `true`, the other iterator visits pairs with the first element being `false`. You then print the values pointed to by the iterators in alternating order:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<bool,int> > v={{true,1},{true,2},{false,3},{false,4},{false,5},{true,6},{false,7},{true,8},{false,9},{false,10},{false,11}};

    auto isTruePair = [](std::pair<bool, int> p) { return p.first; };
    auto isFalsePair = [](std::pair<bool, int> p) { return !p.first; };

    auto trueIt = std::find_if( v.begin(), v.end(), isTruePair );
    auto falseIt = std::find_if( v.begin(), v.end(), isFalsePair );

    while ( trueIt != v.end() || falseIt != v.end() ) {
        if ( falseIt != v.end() ) {
            std::cout << "0," << falseIt->second << '\n';
            falseIt = std::find_if( ++falseIt, v.end(), isFalsePair );
        }

        if ( trueIt != v.end() ) {
            std::cout << "1," << trueIt->second << '\n';
            trueIt = std::find_if( ++trueIt, v.end(), isTruePair );
        }
    }
}
```

I now see that this is basically the same as the `std::partition` idea given in @Smeeheey's answer, except that this version doesn't require moving the elements around.